# How to properly handle non-www to www and http to https redirect on Nginx as proxy?

Tags: nginx, proxy, ubuntu-16.04, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to implement these rules for a single domain and I can't seem to find a proper way to do it online:

- If the user hits http, redirect to `https://www.domain.com`
- If the user hits non-www, redirect to www
- If the user hits `https://www.domain.com` handle proxy to specific IP with port

So far this is what I have:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.io www.domain.io;
        return 301 https://www.domain.io$request_uri;
}


server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.domain.io;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.io/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.io/privkey.pem;

        #MORE SSL BLOCKS


        #remnants, should I remove this?
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://IP_ADDR:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```

I tried adding this between the two server blocks.

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name domain.io;
        return 301 https://www.domain.io$request_uri;
}
```

This breaks SSL on non-www somehow.

The first block works, that's as much as I have figured. Not specifying the protocol redirects to https, but non-www still redirects to non-www.

Networking isn't quite my specialty, so pardon any wrong terminology.

Comment: You do not have SSL enabled for `domain.io`. Do you have a certificate for `domain.io`?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, I have it declared where it says SSL BLOCK, it uses let's encrypt and it currently works if https and www.

Comment: @RichardSmith I see what you meant. It does seem to work if you add the ssl properties before redirecting. Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: If this is the only SSL server, you can put most (if not all) ssl directives outside the `server` blocks, so that both blocks inherit the same values. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for details.

Comment: I'm managing this now to implement subdomains soon, but thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need the solution, I solved the problem by doing what Richard Smith suggested on the comments. I used a Let's Encrypt key on my site, so you just need to replicate the ssl certificate lines on the listen 443 for non-www block.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.io www.domain.io;

        return 301 https://www.domain.io$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        server_name domain.io;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.io/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.io/privkey.pem;

        #SSL_BLOCK

        return 301 https://www.domain.io$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name www.domain.io;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.io/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.io/privkey.pem;

        #SSL_BLOCK


        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://IP_ADDR:PORT;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

}
```